# Pass data from parent component to child component using input, how to implement?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, echarts

There is a parent component with all the logic of the chart, you need to transfer data to the child component using @Input (), that is, so that I can display the chart in any of the components using @Input.

The parent component is logs.component and the child component is echarts.component. It is necessary to pass the data to LoadEcharts(), it contains all the logic of the Chart, that is, that I could call it on any html component

logs.components.ts

```
export class LogsComponent implements OnInit {
  sideNavStatus: boolean = false;
  subscription!: Subscription;
  logs!: Logs[];


  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
  }

  columnDefs = [
    { headerName: 'Username', field: 'username', flex: 1},
    { headerName: 'Event', field: 'event', flex: 1 },
    { headerName: 'Date', field: 'date', flex: 1 }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.LoadLogs();
    this.LoadEcharts();
  }

  LoadLogs(): void {
    this.dataService.getLogs().subscribe(logs => this.logs = logs);
  }

  LoadEcharts(): void {
    const chartDom: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('main') as HTMLElement;
    const myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);

    this.subscription = this.dataService.getLogs().subscribe(data => {
      myChart.setOption(this.initBasicEchart(data))
    })
  }

  private initBasicEchart(data: Logs[]) {

    const result: any = {};

    data.forEach(el => {
      const date = el.date.toString().substring(0, 10);
      if (!result[el.event]) {
        result[el.event] = {};
        if (!result[el.event][date]) {
          result[el.event][date] = 1;
        }
      } else {
        if (!result[el.event][date]) {
          result[el.event][date] = 1;
        } else {
          result[el.event][date] += 1;
        }
      }
    });

    const login = {
      x: Object.keys(result.Login),
      y: Object.values(result.Login)};

    const reg = {
      c: Object.keys(result.Registration),
      z: Object.values(result.Registration)};

    return {
      title: {
        text: 'Graphic login and registration.'
      },
      tooltip: {},
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: (reg.c, login.x)
      },
      yAxis: {
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: 'Login',
          type: 'bar',
          data: login.y,
        },
        {
          name: 'Registration',
          type: 'bar',
          data: reg.z,
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

logs.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid g-0">
    <app-header (sideNavToggled)="sideNavStatus = $event;"></app-header>

    <main>
        <app-sidebar [sideNavStatus]="sideNavStatus"
                     [ngClass]="{'app-side-nav-open': sideNavStatus}"></app-sidebar>

        <div class="display-area p-3" [ngClass]="{'display-area-shrink': sideNavStatus}">
            <p class="fs-1 fw-bold fst-italic text-center">Login and registration statistics.
            </p>

            <app-aggreed
                    *ngIf="logs"
                    [logs]="logs"
                    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
            ></app-aggreed>

        </div>
    </main>
</div>

<app-echarts

></app-echarts>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

echarts.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid g-0">
    <app-header (sideNavToggled)="sideNavStatus = $event;"></app-header>

    <main>
        <app-sidebar [sideNavStatus]="sideNavStatus"
                     [ngClass]="{'app-side-nav-open': sideNavStatus}"></app-sidebar>

        <div class="display-area p-3" [ngClass]="{'display-area-shrink': sideNavStatus}">

            <div
                    id="main"
                    style="width: 500px; height: 300px"

            >
            </div >
        </div>
    </main>
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

```
export class EchartsComponent implements OnInit {
  sideNavStatus: boolean = false;
  subscription!: Subscription;


  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }
}
```

I tried to pass methods to the child component through the input but nothing comes out

Comment: You first have to tell us which component is the parent and which one is the child component. Also tell us which exact data you want to pass to the child

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll edit now

Comment: Neither component has a property decorated with `@Input()`

Comment: That's just the point, I don't understand how to do it, I ask for help, everything that I did before did not work

Comment: I'm assuming you want to pass `logs` to the child?

Comment: Have you read: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction ?

Comment: LoadEcharts() this method is all that needs to be imported in it, is it possible?

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do. Let me add some example code that might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

From your code sample, I'm assuming you're trying to access the `EchartsComponent` ViewChild in the logs component and pass data to it.

Here's an example of how you can do that, minus some pieces from your sample code for brevity...

```js
class LogsComponent {

  @ViewChild(EchartsComponent)
  echartsComponent: EchartsComponent;

  LoadEcharts(): void {
    const chartDom: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('main') as HTMLElement; // <-- not sure what this is
    const myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);  // <-- not sure what this is

    this.subscription = this.dataService.getLogs().subscribe(data => {
      this.echartsComponent.logs = data;
      // `logs` doesn't exist in the current code for EchartsComponent.
      // You'll need to add it.
    });
  }

}
```

What I don't see in your `EchartsComponent` is a `logs` property to set. If you're using a ViewChild in the parent component, you don't have to use @Input on the ViewChild instance, you have programmatic access to the component and can set properties or call methods.

If you want to use `@Input()`, you can do that too:

```js
class EchartsComponent {
  @Input()
  logs: Logs[];
}
```

// logs.component.ts

```js
class LogsComponent {

  LoadEcharts(): void {
    this.subscription = this.dataService.getLogs().subscribe(data => {
      this.logs = data;
    })
  }
}
```

// logs.component.html

```
<app-echarts [logs]="logs"></app-echarts>
```

In this scenario, when the observable for `getLogs()` emits, the property logs is set to the new value. That value, being a new reference is passed to the child component via its input.

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: You're welcome. I added another example showing how an input would work.

Comment: Sorry not what I wanted of course, need to somehow transfer return methods  initBasicEcharts

Comment: `initBasixEcharts` would need to set the value you want to pass to the child (via @Input) or set the value on the child (via @ViewChild)